# Kill all activities when HOME key is pressed android

Tags: android

I have an app which has 4 activities in it.Within app, history activities, i.e. Activities from where I navigated should not be destroyed , so I don't call finish() when I am navigating.

But when I press HOME button I want to kill all activities , So that When I come back to the app , Index screen or say first activity is displayed instead of previous paused activity.

Problem here seems to be, how to differentiate between backs within an app to HOME button.

I saw  few answers regarding this in other questions. Got more confused.
Is there a way other than intercepting HOME KEY PRESS, because as suggested in other threads,
I should not override HOME key press (as it might have side effects)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set [`android:clearTaskOnlaunch="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) on the activity launched from the home screen.

You might also check some of the other attributes you can specify on activity, to tweak it's behavior a bit more.

Comment: Thats perfect ! I have to read documentation properly I guess , I think I have read only 0.1% of documentation ! Its huge ! Thankyou.

Comment: I am trying to accept from past 4 min . It says I have to wait for another 25 sec more before I could accept your answer ! New rules I suppose ! or I didn't know abt it :)

Answer (score 14):

On main activity add:

> android:launchMode="singleTask"
>   android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"

On the others add:

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

This way it will kill off any activity when returning to the app after being in background.

Comment: rather than posting the same answer multiple times, flag the questions as duplicates if they have the same response. It's much more useful to the community.