# Android clear activity list on home button press

Tags: android, android-activity

My application has several activities the first being a logon screen, I want to always force the user to logon even if they have stopped the application using the home button and the restored it. Is there a way to achieve this in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in your Launcher Activity in the manifest and for all other activities use `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` in the manifest.

For a reference, have a look at the link below, this will help you doing what you want.

[Kill all activities when HOME key is pressed android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308088/kill-all-activities-when-home-key-is-pressed-android)

Answer (score 0):

This is my Home button listener. Just attach it to your home button and it will clear the stack upon starting the home activity:  `home_button.setOnClickListener( new HomeButtonListener(this) );` where `this` is a reference to the activity the home button is in.  The name of my home activity is `Home.java` inside my own `activities` package.  Just don't want anyone to get confused by `import activities.Home` and my use of `Home.class`.

```
import activities.Home;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class HomeButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    Activity activity;

    public HomeButtonListener( Activity activity ) 
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for others who see this answer, you can also use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and `android:noHistory="true"` to recreate the activity after coming back to activity after home pressed action.