# Reset the android app after exiting the application

Tags: android

I have developed a camera application in Android using `camera intent`. Its working fine but when I exit from the app and open it again it is showing the app from where I left the application last time. I want the app to start from its start page .

Please suggest a way forward

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'exit the application', pressing back button or home button?

Comment: both back and home button

Comment: you can override the onPause method, then adding some check in onResume to know wich Activity you must launch

Comment: Take a look at @FranciPenov answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5308119/2275818

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kill all activities when HOME key is pressed android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308088/kill-all-activities-when-home-key-is-pressed-android)